# Objective c property inaccessible from swift extension

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have the following app delegate in objc .h file:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign, nonatomic) isWorking BOOL;
@property (strong, nonatomic) XYApplicationController* appController;

@end
```

where the app controller is written in swift:

```
@objc(XYApplicationController)
class ApplicationController: NSObject
```

if I try to use this in an extension in swift:

```
extension AppDelegate {
    func doSomething() -> Bool {
        self.appController  <<<< compiler error: Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'appController'
        self.isWorking <<< works no problem
    }
}
```

Have no idea why and how to fix it, but it seems to be related to swift > objc > swift..

Comment: Your project is in Obj C or in Swift ?

Comment: Both, it's a mixed project. the bridging header has the `#import "AppDelegate.h"

Comment: ya its mixed project but at the time of Project creation which language you chose ? As I can see your project in Obj C bcus your app delegates written in Obj C is that right ?

Comment: I guess your property is actually declared as `@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isWorking;`, right?

Comment: yes, objc project at creation. `isWorking` is accessible.